# Conta invadida e todos os dados retirados

Tags: email

Preciso decifrar esse email cadastrado por um invasor de contas que salvou de forma cifrada em uma das minhas contas de rede social: w*******9@*****.com Tem como?

Comment: Considerando ser uma postagem fora de escopo e um problema que depende de troca de dados de contato e/ou acesso fora do site - o que aumenta o risco de problemas de segurança a todos os envolvidos - os comentários foram removidos e o espaço de comentários desativado. Para entender melhor o site vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Ainda, o [FAQ da Comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/70) é um bom ponto de partida para entender como participar.